# Using Jordan Form to understand $\dot{x} = Ax$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-exponential

I know the flow for the differential equation $\dot{x} = Ax$, where $A$ has no time dependency, is given by $\phi(x,t) = e^{At}$.

Since we want explicit representations we use Jordan Form and properties of the matrix exponential to get $e^{At} = T^{-1}e^{Jt}T$, we then analyse instead the phase portrait of $e^{Jt}$.

However, do the matrices $T$ and $T^{-1}$ not alter the phase portrait for $e^{At}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two linear autonomous systems
$$
\dot{\mathbf{x}} = A \mathbf{x} \tag{1}
$$
and
$$
\dot{\mathbf{x}} = J \mathbf{x} \tag{2}
$$
where $J = P^{-1} A P$ is the *Jordan Canonical Form* of $A$ are topologically equivalent.

Hence, to understand the qualitative properties of the linear system (1), it is often useful to plot the solutions of (2) and understand its stability behavior.